# Docker - unable to copy file after downloading due to intermediate container gets removed

Tags: docker

I have a larger docker file involving a lot of steps (it's single stage however) at the very end of the docker file **I am trying to download a configuration file and then copy it to a specific path and run the program**.

```
EXPOSE 830

RUN wget https://myurl/supervisord.conf

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

However, it seems like when the file get's downloaded successfully the intermediate docker container gets removed an another interim container gets created, and because of that it gives an error saying it can not find the configuration file.

How to avoid this situation? I have also tried using the **`--rm=true`** flag when building the docker file to avoid deleting the intermediate container and **that did not solve the problem.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly put the file at `/etc/supervisord.conf` using `-O` with wget -

```
RUN wget https://myurl/supervisord.conf -O /etc/supervisord.conf
```

In case you do not want this to be done by `wget`, you can do a normal `cp` -

```
RUN cp supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
```

> COPY statement in Dockerfile is basically used to copy contents from
>   host to the relevant docker image layer or the container that you want to create. Your
>   `COPY` is supposed to fail because `supervisord.conf` doesn't exist on
>   your host.